# Three.js - Render an object always on top

Tags: javascript, three.js, render

I'm trying to implement a command arrow that follows the mouse on the screen, but sometimes it ends up hidden behind another object. Is there any way to tweak the z-buffer or something to always render the arrow on top. I would prefer not to create a second scene on top (as seen in the solution here:
[Three.js - Geometry on top of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309289/three-js-geometry-in-top-of-another). Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I used

```
  mesh.renderOrder = zindex || 999;
  mesh.material.depthTest = false;
  mesh.material.depthWrite = false;
  mesh.onBeforeRender = function (renderer) { renderer.clearDepth(); };
```

Comment: I don't know if you want clearDepth like this. I have some problems with these function. But it's working for me without onBeforeRender.

Comment: I think that stringy depends on how your render cycle looks like. I had to hook in to an existing App here, which also rendered a lot of things and iirc I had to clear.

Answer (score 1):

Can you further explain what the "command arrow" is? If you want something to follow the mouse around that's 2D, one option is to create something like:

```
<div id="mouseHover" style="position: absolute; z-index: 999"></div>
```

And then run a script to update the x and y position of the div:

```
<script>
 <!-- if using a library like jQuery, which has a mousemove event handler -->
 $('body').mousemove({
   document.getElementById('mouseHover').style.left = e.pageX;
   document.getElementById('mouseHover').style.top = e.pageY;
 });
</script>
```

If you *really* need something to render in 3D that follows the mouse, the issue is simply relative position. You can create a `THREE.WebGLRenderTarget` with its own scene showing the 3D object on a transparent background, map it to a texture, and apply it to a `THREE.PlaneGeometry` that hovers in front of the camera. I would provide some code for you, but I would need to know more about your particular setup to do so.

Answer (score 1):

This working for me

```
mesh.renderOrder = zindex || 999
mesh.material.depthTest = false 
// UPDATED If you using some models with transparent materials
mesh.material.transparent = true
```

You don't need to set depthWrite to false. More info about depthTest and depthWrite you can get in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37651610/14208501.

If you have some model which have transparent material add to your line transparent also, because transparent materials have in three js own sorting and are rendered after non transparent materials.