# Transparency z-fighting withing a single transparent plane

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am trying to get transparency working within a wavy plane terrain

Here is my demo:

```js
console.clear()
const t = THREE
////////////////////////////////////

const scene = new t.Scene()

const renderer = new t.WebGLRenderer()
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight)
renderer.setPixelRatio(devicePixelRatio)
renderer.setClearColor(0xaaaaaa)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

const perspectiveCamera = new t.PerspectiveCamera(45, innerWidth / innerHeight, 0.1, 1000)
perspectiveCamera.position.set(40, 40, 40)
perspectiveCamera.lookAt(new t.Vector3())

new t.OrbitControls(perspectiveCamera)

const orthoCamera = new t.OrthographicCamera(-innerWidth / 2, innerWidth / 2, innerHeight / 2, -innerHeight / 2, -1, 3)


const terrainWidth = 50
const terrainHeight = 50
const terrainGeometry = new t.PlaneBufferGeometry(terrainWidth, terrainHeight, 100)
const terrainMaterial = new t.ShaderMaterial({
  vertexShader: `
    void main () {
      vec3 newPosition = position;
      
      float dist = distance(newPosition.xy, vec2(0.0));
      newPosition.z = sin(dist) * 5.0;
      
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(newPosition, 1.0);
    }
  `,
  fragmentShader: `
    void main () {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
    }
  `,
  transparent: true
})
const terrain = new t.Mesh(terrainGeometry, terrainMaterial)
terrain.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2
scene.add(terrain)

const cameraDebugEl = document.getElementById('camera-debug')

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, perspectiveCamera)
  
  const camX = perspectiveCamera.position.x.toFixed(2)
  const camY = perspectiveCamera.position.x.toFixed(2)
  const camZ = perspectiveCamera.position.x.toFixed(2)
  
  cameraDebugEl.innerText = `Camera x: ${camX} y: ${camY} z: ${camZ}`
})
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

#camera-debug {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 24px;
  left: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 6px;
}
```

```html
<div id="camera-debug"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>

<!--
Please ignore, this is inlined OrbitControls
-->
<script>

  /**
 * @author qiao / https://github.com/qiao
 * @author mrdoob / http://mrdoob.com
 * @author alteredq / http://alteredqualia.com/
 * @author WestLangley / https://github.com/WestLangley
 * @author erich666 / http://erichaines.com
 */

// This set of controls performs orbiting, dollying (zooming), and panning.
// Unlike TrackballControls, it maintains the "up" direction object.up (+Y by default).
//
//    Orbit - left mouse / touch: one finger move
//    Zoom - middle mouse, or mousewheel / touch: two finger spread or squish
//    Pan - right mouse, or arrow keys / touch: three finger swipe

THREE.OrbitControls = function ( object, domElement ) {

    this.object = object;

    this.domElement = ( domElement !== undefined ) ? domElement : document;

    // Set to false to disable this control
    this.enabled = true;

    // "target" sets the location of focus, where the object orbits around
    this.target = new THREE.Vector3();

    // How far you can dolly in and out ( PerspectiveCamera only )
    this.minDistance = 0;
    this.maxDistance = Infinity;

    // How far you can zoom in and out ( OrthographicCamera only )
    this.minZoom = 0;
    this.maxZoom = Infinity;

    // How far you can orbit vertically, upper and lower limits.
    // Range is 0 to Math.PI radians.
    this.minPolarAngle = 0; // radians
    this.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI; // radians

    // How far you can orbit horizontally, upper and lower limits.
    // If set, must be a sub-interval of the interval [ - Math.PI, Math.PI ].
    this.minAzimuthAngle = - Infinity; // radians
    this.maxAzimuthAngle = Infinity; // radians

    // Set to true to enable damping (inertia)
    // If damping is enabled, you must call controls.update() in your animation loop
    this.enableDamping = false;
    this.dampingFactor = 0.25;

    // This option actually enables dollying in and out; left as "zoom" for backwards compatibility.
    // Set to false to disable zooming
    this.enableZoom = true;
    this.zoomSpeed = 1.0;

    // Set to false to disable rotating
    this.enableRotate = true;
    this.rotateSpeed = 1.0;

    // Set to false to disable panning
    this.enablePan = true;
    this.keyPanSpeed = 7.0; // pixels moved per arrow key push

    // Set to true to automatically rotate around the target
    // If auto-rotate is enabled, you must call controls.update() in your animation loop
    this.autoRotate = false;
    this.autoRotateSpeed = 2.0; // 30 seconds per round when fps is 60

    // Set to false to disable use of the keys
    this.enableKeys = true;

    // The four arrow keys
    this.keys = { LEFT: 37, UP: 38, RIGHT: 39, BOTTOM: 40 };

    // Mouse buttons
    this.mouseButtons = { ORBIT: THREE.MOUSE.LEFT, ZOOM: THREE.MOUSE.MIDDLE, PAN: THREE.MOUSE.RIGHT };

    // for reset
    this.target0 = this.target.clone();
    this.position0 = this.object.position.clone();
    this.zoom0 = this.object.zoom;

    //
    // public methods
    //

    this.getPolarAngle = function () {

        return spherical.phi;

    };

    this.getAzimuthalAngle = function () {

        return spherical.theta;

    };

    this.reset = function () {

        scope.target.copy( scope.target0 );
        scope.object.position.copy( scope.position0 );
        scope.object.zoom = scope.zoom0;

        scope.object.updateProjectionMatrix();
        scope.dispatchEvent( changeEvent );

        scope.update();

        state = STATE.NONE;

    };

    // this method is exposed, but perhaps it would be better if we can make it private...
    this.update = function () {

        var offset = new THREE.Vector3();

        // so camera.up is the orbit axis
        var quat = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromUnitVectors( object.up, new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ) );
        var quatInverse = quat.clone().inverse();

        var lastPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
        var lastQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();

        return function update() {

            var position = scope.object.position;

            offset.copy( position ).sub( scope.target );

            // rotate offset to "y-axis-is-up" space
            offset.applyQuaternion( quat );

            // angle from z-axis around y-axis
            spherical.setFromVector3( offset );

            if ( scope.autoRotate && state === STATE.NONE ) {

                rotateLeft( getAutoRotationAngle() );

            }

            spherical.theta += sphericalDelta.theta;
            spherical.phi += sphericalDelta.phi;

            // restrict theta to be between desired limits
            spherical.theta = Math.max( scope.minAzimuthAngle, Math.min( scope.maxAzimuthAngle, spherical.theta ) );

            // restrict phi to be between desired limits
            spherical.phi = Math.max( scope.minPolarAngle, Math.min( scope.maxPolarAngle, spherical.phi ) );

            spherical.makeSafe();


            spherical.radius *= scale;

            // restrict radius to be between desired limits
            spherical.radius = Math.max( scope.minDistance, Math.min( scope.maxDistance, spherical.radius ) );

            // move target to panned location
            scope.target.add( panOffset );

            offset.setFromSpherical( spherical );

            // rotate offset back to "camera-up-vector-is-up" space
            offset.applyQuaternion( quatInverse );

            position.copy( scope.target ).add( offset );

            scope.object.lookAt( scope.target );

            if ( scope.enableDamping === true ) {

                sphericalDelta.theta *= ( 1 - scope.dampingFactor );
                sphericalDelta.phi *= ( 1 - scope.dampingFactor );

            } else {

                sphericalDelta.set( 0, 0, 0 );

            }

            scale = 1;
            panOffset.set( 0, 0, 0 );

            // update condition is:
            // min(camera displacement, camera rotation in radians)^2 > EPS
            // using small-angle approximation cos(x/2) = 1 - x^2 / 8

            if ( zoomChanged ||
                lastPosition.distanceToSquared( scope.object.position ) > EPS ||
                8 * ( 1 - lastQuaternion.dot( scope.object.quaternion ) ) > EPS ) {

                scope.dispatchEvent( changeEvent );

                lastPosition.copy( scope.object.position );
                lastQuaternion.copy( scope.object.quaternion );
                zoomChanged = false;

                return true;

            }

            return false;

        };

    }();

    this.dispose = function () {

        scope.domElement.removeEventListener( 'contextmenu', onContextMenu, false );
        scope.domElement.removeEventListener( 'mousedown', onMouseDown, false );
        scope.domElement.removeEventListener( 'wheel', onMouseWheel, false );

        scope.domElement.removeEventListener( 'touchstart', onTouchStart, false );
        scope.domElement.removeEventListener( 'touchend', onTouchEnd, false );
        scope.domElement.removeEventListener( 'touchmove', onTouchMove, false );

        document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
        document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onMouseUp, false );

        window.removeEventListener( 'keydown', onKeyDown, false );

        //scope.dispatchEvent( { type: 'dispose' } ); // should this be added here?

    };

    //
    // internals
    //

    var scope = this;

    var changeEvent = { type: 'change' };
    var startEvent = { type: 'start' };
    var endEvent = { type: 'end' };

    var STATE = { NONE: - 1, ROTATE: 0, DOLLY: 1, PAN: 2, TOUCH_ROTATE: 3, TOUCH_DOLLY: 4, TOUCH_PAN: 5 };

    var state = STATE.NONE;

    var EPS = 0.000001;

    // current position in spherical coordinates
    var spherical = new THREE.Spherical();
    var sphericalDelta = new THREE.Spherical();

    var scale = 1;
    var panOffset = new THREE.Vector3();
    var zoomChanged = false;

    var rotateStart = new THREE.Vector2();
    var rotateEnd = new THREE.Vector2();
    var rotateDelta = new THREE.Vector2();

    var panStart = new THREE.Vector2();
    var panEnd = new THREE.Vector2();
    var panDelta = new THREE.Vector2();

    var dollyStart = new THREE.Vector2();
    var dollyEnd = new THREE.Vector2();
    var dollyDelta = new THREE.Vector2();

    function getAutoRotationAngle() {

        return 2 * Math.PI / 60 / 60 * scope.autoRotateSpeed;

    }

    function getZoomScale() {

        return Math.pow( 0.95, scope.zoomSpeed );

    }

    function rotateLeft( angle ) {

        sphericalDelta.theta -= angle;

    }

    function rotateUp( angle ) {

        sphericalDelta.phi -= angle;

    }

    var panLeft = function () {

        var v = new THREE.Vector3();

        return function panLeft( distance, objectMatrix ) {

            v.setFromMatrixColumn( objectMatrix, 0 ); // get X column of objectMatrix
            v.multiplyScalar( - distance );

            panOffset.add( v );

        };

    }();

    var panUp = function () {

        var v = new THREE.Vector3();

        return function panUp( distance, objectMatrix ) {

            v.setFromMatrixColumn( objectMatrix, 1 ); // get Y column of objectMatrix
            v.multiplyScalar( distance );

            panOffset.add( v );

        };

    }();

    // deltaX and deltaY are in pixels; right and down are positive
    var pan = function () {

        var offset = new THREE.Vector3();

        return function pan( deltaX, deltaY ) {

            var element = scope.domElement === document ? scope.domElement.body : scope.domElement;

            if ( scope.object instanceof THREE.PerspectiveCamera ) {

                // perspective
                var position = scope.object.position;
                offset.copy( position ).sub( scope.target );
                var targetDistance = offset.length();

                // half of the fov is center to top of screen
                targetDistance *= Math.tan( ( scope.object.fov / 2 ) * Math.PI / 180.0 );

                // we actually don't use screenWidth, since perspective camera is fixed to screen height
                panLeft( 2 * deltaX * targetDistance / element.clientHeight, scope.object.matrix );
                panUp( 2 * deltaY * targetDistance / element.clientHeight, scope.object.matrix );

            } else if ( scope.object instanceof THREE.OrthographicCamera ) {

                // orthographic
                panLeft( deltaX * ( scope.object.right - scope.object.left ) / scope.object.zoom / element.clientWidth, scope.object.matrix );
                panUp( deltaY * ( scope.object.top - scope.object.bottom ) / scope.object.zoom / element.clientHeight, scope.object.matrix );

            } else {

                // camera neither orthographic nor perspective
                console.warn( 'WARNING: OrbitControls.js encountered an unknown camera type - pan disabled.' );
                scope.enablePan = false;

            }

        };

    }();

    function dollyIn( dollyScale ) {

        if ( scope.object instanceof THREE.PerspectiveCamera ) {

            scale /= dollyScale;

        } else if ( scope.object instanceof THREE.OrthographicCamera ) {

            scope.object.zoom = Math.max( scope.minZoom, Math.min( scope.maxZoom, scope.object.zoom * dollyScale ) );
            scope.object.updateProjectionMatrix();
            zoomChanged = true;

        } else {

            console.warn( 'WARNING: OrbitControls.js encountered an unknown camera type - dolly/zoom disabled.' );
            scope.enableZoom = false;

        }

    }

    function dollyOut( dollyScale ) {

        if ( scope.object instanceof THREE.PerspectiveCamera ) {

            scale *= dollyScale;

        } else if ( scope.object instanceof THREE.OrthographicCamera ) {

            scope.object.zoom = Math.max( scope.minZoom, Math.min( scope.maxZoom, scope.object.zoom / dollyScale ) );
            scope.object.updateProjectionMatrix();
            zoomChanged = true;

        } else {

            console.warn( 'WARNING: OrbitControls.js encountered an unknown camera type - dolly/zoom disabled.' );
            scope.enableZoom = false;

        }

    }

    //
    // event callbacks - update the object state
    //

    function handleMouseDownRotate( event ) {

        //console.log( 'handleMouseDownRotate' );

        rotateStart.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );

    }

    function handleMouseDownDolly( event ) {

        //console.log( 'handleMouseDownDolly' );

        dollyStart.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );

    }

    function handleMouseDownPan( event ) {

        //console.log( 'handleMouseDownPan' );

        panStart.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );

    }

    function handleMouseMoveRotate( event ) {

        //console.log( 'handleMouseMoveRotate' );

        rotateEnd.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );
        rotateDelta.subVectors( rotateEnd, rotateStart );

        var element = scope.domElement === document ? scope.domElement.body : scope.domElement;

        // rotating across whole screen goes 360 degrees around
        rotateLeft( 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.x / element.clientWidth * scope.rotateSpeed );

        // rotating up and down along whole screen attempts to go 360, but limited to 180
        rotateUp( 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.y / element.clientHeight * scope.rotateSpeed );

        rotateStart.copy( rotateEnd );

        scope.update();

    }

    function handleMouseMoveDolly( event ) {

        //console.log( 'handleMouseMoveDolly' );

        dollyEnd.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );

        dollyDelta.subVectors( dollyEnd, dollyStart );

        if ( dollyDelta.y > 0 ) {

            dollyIn( getZoomScale() );

        } else if ( dollyDelta.y < 0 ) {

            dollyOut( getZoomScale() );

        }

        dollyStart.copy( dollyEnd );

        scope.update();

    }

    function handleMouseMovePan( event ) {

        //console.log( 'handleMouseMovePan' );

        panEnd.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );

        panDelta.subVectors( panEnd, panStart );

        pan( panDelta.x, panDelta.y );

        panStart.copy( panEnd );

        scope.update();

    }

    function handleMouseUp( event ) {

        // console.log( 'handleMouseUp' );

    }

    function handleMouseWheel( event ) {

        // console.log( 'handleMouseWheel' );

        if ( event.deltaY < 0 ) {

            dollyOut( getZoomScale() );

        } else if ( event.deltaY > 0 ) {

            dollyIn( getZoomScale() );

        }

        scope.update();

    }

    function handleKeyDown( event ) {

        //console.log( 'handleKeyDown' );

        switch ( event.keyCode ) {

            case scope.keys.UP:
                pan( 0, scope.keyPanSpeed );
                scope.update();
                break;

            case scope.keys.BOTTOM:
                pan( 0, - scope.keyPanSpeed );
                scope.update();
                break;

            case scope.keys.LEFT:
                pan( scope.keyPanSpeed, 0 );
                scope.update();
                break;

            case scope.keys.RIGHT:
                pan( - scope.keyPanSpeed, 0 );
                scope.update();
                break;

        }

    }

    function handleTouchStartRotate( event ) {

        //console.log( 'handleTouchStartRotate' );

        rotateStart.set( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX, event.touches[ 0 ].pageY );

    }

    function handleTouchStartDolly( event ) {

        //console.log( 'handleTouchStartDolly' );

        var dx = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - event.touches[ 1 ].pageX;
        var dy = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - event.touches[ 1 ].pageY;

        var distance = Math.sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy );

        dollyStart.set( 0, distance );

    }

    function handleTouchStartPan( event ) {

        //console.log( 'handleTouchStartPan' );

        panStart.set( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX, event.touches[ 0 ].pageY );

    }

    function handleTouchMoveRotate( event ) {

        //console.log( 'handleTouchMoveRotate' );

        rotateEnd.set( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX, event.touches[ 0 ].pageY );
        rotateDelta.subVectors( rotateEnd, rotateStart );

        var element = scope.domElement === document ? scope.domElement.body : scope.domElement;

        // rotating across whole screen goes 360 degrees around
        rotateLeft( 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.x / element.clientWidth * scope.rotateSpeed );

        // rotating up and down along whole screen attempts to go 360, but limited to 180
        rotateUp( 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.y / element.clientHeight * scope.rotateSpeed );

        rotateStart.copy( rotateEnd );

        scope.update();

    }

    function handleTouchMoveDolly( event ) {

        //console.log( 'handleTouchMoveDolly' );

        var dx = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - event.touches[ 1 ].pageX;
        var dy = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - event.touches[ 1 ].pageY;

        var distance = Math.sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy );

        dollyEnd.set( 0, distance );

        dollyDelta.subVectors( dollyEnd, dollyStart );

        if ( dollyDelta.y > 0 ) {

            dollyOut( getZoomScale() );

        } else if ( dollyDelta.y < 0 ) {

            dollyIn( getZoomScale() );

        }

        dollyStart.copy( dollyEnd );

        scope.update();

    }

    function handleTouchMovePan( event ) {

        //console.log( 'handleTouchMovePan' );

        panEnd.set( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX, event.touches[ 0 ].pageY );

        panDelta.subVectors( panEnd, panStart );

        pan( panDelta.x, panDelta.y );

        panStart.copy( panEnd );

        scope.update();

    }

    function handleTouchEnd( event ) {

        //console.log( 'handleTouchEnd' );

    }

    //
    // event handlers - FSM: listen for events and reset state
    //

    function onMouseDown( event ) {

        if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

        event.preventDefault();

        if ( event.button === scope.mouseButtons.ORBIT ) {

            if ( scope.enableRotate === false ) return;

            handleMouseDownRotate( event );

            state = STATE.ROTATE;

        } else if ( event.button === scope.mouseButtons.ZOOM ) {

            if ( scope.enableZoom === false ) return;

            handleMouseDownDolly( event );

            state = STATE.DOLLY;

        } else if ( event.button === scope.mouseButtons.PAN ) {

            if ( scope.enablePan === false ) return;

            handleMouseDownPan( event );

            state = STATE.PAN;

        }

        if ( state !== STATE.NONE ) {

            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onMouseUp, false );

            scope.dispatchEvent( startEvent );

        }

    }

    function onMouseMove( event ) {

        if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

        event.preventDefault();

        if ( state === STATE.ROTATE ) {

            if ( scope.enableRotate === false ) return;

            handleMouseMoveRotate( event );

        } else if ( state === STATE.DOLLY ) {

            if ( scope.enableZoom === false ) return;

            handleMouseMoveDolly( event );

        } else if ( state === STATE.PAN ) {

            if ( scope.enablePan === false ) return;

            handleMouseMovePan( event );

        }

    }

    function onMouseUp( event ) {

        if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

        handleMouseUp( event );

        document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
        document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onMouseUp, false );

        scope.dispatchEvent( endEvent );

        state = STATE.NONE;

    }

    function onMouseWheel( event ) {

        if ( scope.enabled === false || scope.enableZoom === false || ( state !== STATE.NONE && state !== STATE.ROTATE ) ) return;

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        handleMouseWheel( event );

        scope.dispatchEvent( startEvent ); // not sure why these are here...
        scope.dispatchEvent( endEvent );

    }

    function onKeyDown( event ) {

        if ( scope.enabled === false || scope.enableKeys === false || scope.enablePan === false ) return;

        handleKeyDown( event );

    }

    function onTouchStart( event ) {

        if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

        switch ( event.touches.length ) {

            case 1: // one-fingered touch: rotate

                if ( scope.enableRotate === false ) return;

                handleTouchStartRotate( event );

                state = STATE.TOUCH_ROTATE;

                break;

            case 2: // two-fingered touch: dolly

                if ( scope.enableZoom === false ) return;

                handleTouchStartDolly( event );

                state = STATE.TOUCH_DOLLY;

                break;

            case 3: // three-fingered touch: pan

                if ( scope.enablePan === false ) return;

                handleTouchStartPan( event );

                state = STATE.TOUCH_PAN;

                break;

            default:

                state = STATE.NONE;

        }

        if ( state !== STATE.NONE ) {

            scope.dispatchEvent( startEvent );

        }

    }

    function onTouchMove( event ) {

        if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        switch ( event.touches.length ) {

            case 1: // one-fingered touch: rotate

                if ( scope.enableRotate === false ) return;
                if ( state !== STATE.TOUCH_ROTATE ) return; // is this needed?...

                handleTouchMoveRotate( event );

                break;

            case 2: // two-fingered touch: dolly

                if ( scope.enableZoom === false ) return;
                if ( state !== STATE.TOUCH_DOLLY ) return; // is this needed?...

                handleTouchMoveDolly( event );

                break;

            case 3: // three-fingered touch: pan

                if ( scope.enablePan === false ) return;
                if ( state !== STATE.TOUCH_PAN ) return; // is this needed?...

                handleTouchMovePan( event );

                break;

            default:

                state = STATE.NONE;

        }

    }

    function onTouchEnd( event ) {

        if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

        handleTouchEnd( event );

        scope.dispatchEvent( endEvent );

        state = STATE.NONE;

    }

    function onContextMenu( event ) {

        event.preventDefault();

    }

    //

    scope.domElement.addEventListener( 'contextmenu', onContextMenu, false );

    scope.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onMouseDown, false );
    scope.domElement.addEventListener( 'wheel', onMouseWheel, false );

    scope.domElement.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onTouchStart, false );
    scope.domElement.addEventListener( 'touchend', onTouchEnd, false );
    scope.domElement.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onTouchMove, false );

    window.addEventListener( 'keydown', onKeyDown, false );

    // force an update at start

    this.update();

};

THREE.OrbitControls.prototype = Object.create( THREE.EventDispatcher.prototype );
THREE.OrbitControls.prototype.constructor = THREE.OrbitControls;

Object.defineProperties( THREE.OrbitControls.prototype, {

    center: {

        get: function () {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .center has been renamed to .target' );
            return this.target;

        }

    },

    // backward compatibility

    noZoom: {

        get: function () {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noZoom has been deprecated. Use .enableZoom instead.' );
            return ! this.enableZoom;

        },

        set: function ( value ) {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noZoom has been deprecated. Use .enableZoom instead.' );
            this.enableZoom = ! value;

        }

    },

    noRotate: {

        get: function () {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noRotate has been deprecated. Use .enableRotate instead.' );
            return ! this.enableRotate;

        },

        set: function ( value ) {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noRotate has been deprecated. Use .enableRotate instead.' );
            this.enableRotate = ! value;

        }

    },

    noPan: {

        get: function () {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noPan has been deprecated. Use .enablePan instead.' );
            return ! this.enablePan;

        },

        set: function ( value ) {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noPan has been deprecated. Use .enablePan instead.' );
            this.enablePan = ! value;

        }

    },

    noKeys: {

        get: function () {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noKeys has been deprecated. Use .enableKeys instead.' );
            return ! this.enableKeys;

        },

        set: function ( value ) {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noKeys has been deprecated. Use .enableKeys instead.' );
            this.enableKeys = ! value;

        }

    },

    staticMoving: {

        get: function () {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .staticMoving has been deprecated. Use .enableDamping instead.' );
            return ! this.enableDamping;

        },

        set: function ( value ) {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .staticMoving has been deprecated. Use .enableDamping instead.' );
            this.enableDamping = ! value;

        }

    },

    dynamicDampingFactor: {

        get: function () {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .dynamicDampingFactor has been renamed. Use .dampingFactor instead.' );
            return this.dampingFactor;

        },

        set: function ( value ) {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .dynamicDampingFactor has been renamed. Use .dampingFactor instead.' );
            this.dampingFactor = value;

        }

    }

} );

</script>
```

Can someone please explain why the transparency works differently depending on the camera position? I guess this is a WebGL problem in general, but I am not sure what to look for.

Is there a way to make it look the same, regardless of the camera angle?

Comment: I don't see any z-fighting in your demo. Please post some screenshots of what you're seeing.

Comment: @TheJim01 perhaps I should rephrase my question. Do you see the difference in the mesh rendering when you rotate the camera? You get different transparency depending on which side are you looking at. What is this phenomena called in WebGL?

Comment: I could see it. https://codepen.io/cdeep/pen/rNzVvyR

Comment: Yes. It is an effect of "render order". Think of it as the GPU drawing the triangles in the order in which they are defined. Subsequent triangles use the depth/color buffers to determine what to draw and how to blend. So if the first triangle is behind the second, the second will draw on top and blend the colors. But if the second triangle is behind the first, the first triangle will _occlude_ the second.

Comment: so in terms of a single mesh, my best best is to render individual triangles and sort them? is there a straightforward threejs solution? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments by TheJim01 above, TIL about depthWrite option of Material:
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material.depthWrite

Made a codepen here:
https://codepen.io/cdeep/pen/rNzVvyR

```js
const terrainMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  vertexShader: ``,
  fragmentShader: ``,
  transparent: true,
  depthWrite: false,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
});
```

Also added `side: THREE.DoubleSide` since it looked better that way.

P.S: This led me to depthWrite -> https://discourse.threejs.org/t/render-order-issue-what-else-affects-it-besides-order-added-to-the-scene/15105