How do I make a mesh with an EdgesGeometry always on top but still make the outline behind the mesh hidden?
How to make the box on the right? I used depthTest false on the box and its outline to make it always on top of other mesh but the outline is now ignoring the box depth.

Here is the sample code the display the image on the left
https://jsfiddle.net/icesnake/t6no2a84/13/
    var camera, scene, renderer;
    var geometry, material, greenMesh;

    init();
    animate();

    function init() {

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
        camera.position.z = 5;

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
        material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00,side:THREE.DoubleSide});
            material.depthTest = false;
        material.transparent = false;
        material.opacity = 1;
        greenMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        var edgeMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
          color: 'black',
          depthTest: false,
          depthWrite: false,
        });
        var edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(geometry);
        var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments(edges, edgeMaterial);
        wireframe.renderOrder = 1;
        greenMesh.add(wireframe);
        greenMesh.renderOrder = 1;
        
        scene.add(greenMesh);
        
        material3 = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({emissive: 0x00ffff,side:THREE.DoubleSide});
        
        geometry3 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1,1,1 );

        blueMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry3, material3 );
        blueMesh.position.z = 0.5;
       
        scene.add(blueMesh);

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    }

    function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame( animate );

        greenMesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
        greenMesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

        renderer.render( scene, camera );

    }

I tried different combinations of depthTest, depthWrite and renderOrder and I cannot seem to make the output I desire.

Here is one way. It depends on your use case. https://jsfiddle.net/1v4yjnbh/. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13309722/1461008.

Thanks for the reply. It does indeed work on your jsfiddle. But wanted to ask if it can be done with a single scene? Maybe layers? I already have 4 scenes in my app, do i have to add another scene just to support this always on top feature? Thank you.

If you are careful to control the render order, you can have a single render call and use mesh.onBeforeRender = function( renderer ) { renderer.clearDepth(); }; https://jsfiddle.net/9t74d2jo/
