# three.js: how to control rendering order

Tags: optimization, 3d, rendering, three.js

Am using three.js

How can I control the rendering order? Let's say I have three plane geometries, and want to render them in a specific order regardless of their spatial position.

thanks

Comment: check out the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76147276/6908282).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can set

```
renderer.sortObjects = false;
```

and the objects will be rendered in the order they were added to the scene.

Alternatively, you can leave `sortObjects` as `true`, the default, and specify for each object a value for `object.renderOrder`.

For more detail, see [Transparent objects in Threejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994944/transparent-objects-in-threejs/15995475#15995475)

Another thing you can do is use the approach described here: [How to change the zOrder of object with Threejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666570/how-to-change-the-zorder-of-object-with-threejs)

three.js r.71

Comment: Thanks man, I made some experiments with your renderDepth suggestion and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

for threejs r70 and higher is renderDepth removed.

Comment: What is the workaround for that? I dont like to have multiple overlapping scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Using object.renderDepth worked in my case.  I had a glass case and bubbles inside that were transparent.  The bubbles were getting lost at certain angles.

So, setting their renderDepth to a high number and playing with other elements depths in the scene fixed the issue.  Hooking up a dat.gui control to the renderDepth property made it very easy to tweak what needed to be at what depth to make the scene work.

So, in my fishScene, I have gravel, tank and bubbles.  I hooked up the gravel mesh with a dat.gui control and with in a few seconds, I had the depth I needed.

```
this.gui.add(this.fishScene.gravel, "renderDepth", 0, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

i had a bunch of objects which was cloned from a for loop in random position x and y... and obj.z ++, so they would line up in line.. including obj.renderOrder ++; in the loop solved my issue.