# Transparent objects in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I am trying to write a small program in Three.js that displays two spheres, one inside the other. The radius of sphere 2 is supposed to oscillate between 0.5 and 1.5 while the radius of sphere1 is always 1.0. Each sphere is transparent (opacity: 0.5) so that it would be possible to see the smaller sphere contained in the larger one. Of course the roles of "smaller" and "larger" change as the radius of sphere 2 varies.

The problem now is that Three.js makes the first sphere transparent. I define in my program but not the second one. If I first define sphere 1 then it becomes transparent, but then sphere 2 is completely opaque. If I first define sphere 2 then this is the transparent one. The order of adding them to the scene plays no role.

I include a minimal program below that shows what is going on (without the animation). In its current state only sphere 1 is visible and it is not transparent. If I define sphere 1 before sphere 2 then sphere 1 becomes transparent, but sphere 2 is no longer transparent. Changing sphere 2's radius to 1.2 will then hide sphere 1.

Is there a way to make both spheres transparent?

```javascript
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

camera.position.set(0, 0, 3);
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
scene.add(camera);

var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x555555 );
scene.add(ambient);

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
light.position = camera.position;
scene.add(light);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Definition 2
var geometry2 = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.8,32,24);
var material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x0000ff, transparent: true, opacity: 0.5});
var sphere2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, material2);

// Definition 1
var geometry1 = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1.0,32,24);
var material1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x00ff00, transparent: true, opacity: 0.5});
var sphere1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1);

scene.add(sphere1);
scene.add(sphere2);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Both your spheres are transparent, and are remaining so. What is happening is that the smaller sphere is not being rendered at all.

Transparency in WebGL is tricky. You can google the issue to find out more about it.

But you have stumbled upon an issue related to how *three.js in particular* handles transparency.

The `WebGLRenderer` in three.js sorts objects based upon their distance from the camera, and renders transparent objects in order from farthest to closest. (This is an important point: It sorts *objects* based on their *position*, and renders *objects* in the sorted order.)

So for two transparent objects to render correctly, the object that is in back -- the smaller sphere in your case -- must be rendered first. Otherwise, it will not be rendered at all, due to the depth buffer.

But in your case, you have two spheres that are in the same location, and hence are equidistant from the camera. That is the problem -- which one to render first; it is a toss-up.

So you need to place the smaller sphere further away from the camera than the larger sphere in order for the scene to render correctly.

One solution is to move the smaller sphere back a little.

Another solution is to set `renderer.sortObjects = false`. Then the objects will render in the order they are added to the scene. In that case, be sure to add the smaller sphere to the scene first.

A third solution is to set `material1.depthWrite = false` and `material2.depthWrite = false`.

EDIT:

Renderable objects having `material.transparent = false` (opaque objects) are rendered before objects having `material.transparent = true` (transparent objects).

So a fourth solution is to make the smaller sphere opaque so it is rendered first.

New feature for r.71:

There is now an `Object3D.renderOrder` property. Within each class of object (opaque or transparent), objects are rendered in the order specified by `object.renderOrder`. The default value of `renderOrder` is `0`. Note that `renderOrder` is not inherited by child objects; you must set it for each renderable object.

Objects with the same `renderOrder` (ties), are sorted by depth, as described above.

So a fifth solution is to set `renderOrder = 1` for the larger sphere. This is likely the best solution in your case.

three.js r.71

Comment: What does depthWrite do exactly ? What are the drawbacks (perfs, new bugs, ...?) ?

Comment: I think depth write signals that the objects should write their own depths, meaning that they figure out their depth in a scene based on their distance to the camera. If you disable it, you can override a new depth

Comment: The `renderOrder` feature in r.71 worked for me.  NOTE: You have to set it on children objects.  Setting it on a parent object does not apply to the children.

Comment: Adding `depthWrite: false` was the solution, thanks! So I am using now: `var material_plane = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: drawcol, side: THREE.DoubleSide, opacity: 0.5, transparent: true, depthWrite: false});`

Comment: @Matheretter It is preferred that you up-vote answers on this site (if you want), instead of adding 'thank you' comments.

Comment: I actually added some more code to help others figuring out how to use one of the solutions correcly. That was not a pure thank you... upvote done.

Comment: @WestLangley thanks for answer this transparency issue was making me nuts and the situation worse when have multiple transparent object render one by one many thanks for renderOrder

Comment: depthwrite fixed it for me

Comment: Oh dear... this solved hours and hours of work... Please accept my sincere gratitude, dear @WestLangley and Everyone who participated... You are astronomically magnificent! Please have a pleasant time and stay safe! Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50690473/threejs-mesh-becomes-invisible-when-inside-another-mesh

Comment: Thank you, I fixed a bug that was there since 2 years using renderOrder = 1!

Comment: I needed an opaque object to render ontop of a transparent object, so I ended up setting `material.transparent = true` on the opaque object to ensure to `renderOrder` of the opaque object places it ontop of the transparent object. 

The fact that `transparent = true` objects are rendered after `transparent = false` objects was the missing piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 12):

A couple of comments.

First.  If you are going to ask a question that expects people to review code, put it on [JSFiddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSFiddle).  If you do, you will get more people taking a peek.  That having been said, here is a slightly modified version of your code on JSFiddle, please use it as a guide for future questions. [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/crossphire/9eXKN/)

```javascript
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

camera.position.set(0, 0, 3);
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
scene.add(camera);

var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x555555);
scene.add(ambient);

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0XFFFFFF);
light.position = camera.position;
scene.add(light);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

renderer.sortObjects = false;

// Definition 2
var geometry2 = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.8, 32, 24);
var material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x0000ff, transparent: true, opacity: 0.5});
var sphere2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, material2);

// Definition 1
var geometry1 = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1.0, 32, 24);
var material1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xff0000, transparent: true, opacity: 0.5});
var sphere1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1);

scene.add(sphere2);
scene.add(sphere1);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

In your code I've set sortObjects to false and then changed the order that the spheres were added to the scene.  This was done because of the information in the next two links:

- [WebGL transparent planes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165345/three-js-webgl-transparent-planes-hiding-other-planes-behind-them)
- [Transparent texture behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763603/transparent-textures-behaviour-in-webgl)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to check my code and reply. Setting `rendered.sortObjects` to `false` makes the final result depend on the order I add the objects to the scene, as explained in the later answer by WestLangley. The problem is that I want to animate the scene and for some frames it would be better to have one sphere drawn first and fore some other frames the other sphere.

Answer (score 3):

For me it works with a transparent pix...
With others solutions i've got artefact with my "clouds shaders"

1/ Wireframe:

```javascript
    <meshBasicMaterial wireframe />
```

[image]

2/ Opacity & transparency:

```javascript
<meshBasicMaterial opacity="0" transparent="true" thickness="0" transmission="0" depthTest={true}/>
```

[image]

3/ Map with transparent texture:

```javascript
    import { useLoader } from '@react-three/fiber'
    import pixTrans from './assets/pix.png' // transparent pixel
    const [textureTrans] = useLoader(THREE.TextureLoader, [pixTrans]) 
    
    return (
        <mesh position={[0, 2, 0]}>
          <boxGeometry args={[3, 5, 3]}/>
          <meshBasicMaterial map={textureTrans} alphaTest="0.5" />
        </mesh>
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth I could not solve the same problem using the methods above but found that having:

```javascript
scene = new THREE.Scene();
group = new THREE.Group();
scene.add(group);
```

in my init() and then adding the frontside mesh to the scene, but the backside mesh to group solved the problem. i.e.:

```javascript
var materialfront = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                           opacity:1, map:texture});
materialfront.transparent = true;
materialfront.side = THREE.FrontSide;
frontthing = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materialfront);
frontthing.renderOrder = 2;
scene.add(frontthing);
```

then

```javascript
var texture2 = texture.clone();
texture2.needsUpdate = true;
var materialBack = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                                opacity:0.1, map: texture2})
materialBack.transparent = true;
materialBack.side = THREE.BackSide;
backthing = new THREE.Mesh(geometryback, materialBack);
backthing.renderOrder = 1;
group.add(backthing);
```

My material map was a transparent .png texture.

I can not explain why other suggested methods did not work for me, but I hope the above might help some one in a similar position.