# Three js render child mesh always before his parent

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have scene() and meshes:

scene:

```
scene.add(layer1)
layer.add(layer2)
layer2.add(layer3)
```

Wanted result is:

layer1 covered by layer2 and covered by layer3.

It works fine, but when i go far away with camera, there start to be loss precision problem and looks like this:
(layers are not correctly rendered one to another)

[image]

i tried to solve by materials,

```
layer2.material.depthTest = 0;
layer3.material.depthTest = 0;
```

works fine, but there is problem with another object between camera and layers.
[image]

Do exist best practice for solution?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994944/transparent-objects-in-threejs/15995475#15995475

Comment: Thank you, i understand that topic solving issue about ordering object and covering one behind another.
But this is not what I'm solving. I have correct order of layers. Problem is when i zoom out (move far form layers) with camera,  always starts a problem with partial covering (image1). As i understand it is caused by loss precision in webgl on bigger distances, the mathematics is not so accurate. I need to have clouds forced before the parent object, but not before the other object like another planets,or like image2. Did i understand correctly? or there is solution not recognized by my?

Comment: What parameters are you passing to your camera constructor? Are your clouds and earth at the same render depth?

Comment: camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.01,1000000); renderDepth is not set r71, renderer.sortObjects = 0;

Comment: Read https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Depth_Buffer_Precision and try increasing your near plane value to the largest value you can.

Comment: If i change near and far to 1,10000, problem still exists, but i need to see far than 10000. I know precision problem, and don't trying to solve this. I'm finding the way how to push one object before another object by force, but not on the top of the whole scene (depthtest), only on his parent. Like in CSS  <div>layer one<div>layer two<div>layer three</div></div></div> solving the problem.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a simple, 50-line, live example that demonstrates the problem? -- not your entire project.

Comment: (on load zoom out camera!)
http://jsfiddle.net/QHssJ/16/ with tepthTest : 0 this i want on planet, but not affect on all neighborhood object (redball, floor).
http://jsfiddle.net/QHssJ/17/ this is what i have, but i need to avoid partial covering. atmosphere must be always before the planet. not other objects.

Comment: Set the near plane to 100 and increase the scale of the clouds.

Comment: That will not solve the problem, in each time there will be a limited distance where the issue will be visible:
http://jsfiddle.net/QHssJ/18/

Comment: Do exist somethng like z-index in css? Will prioritize an element only in child elements?
planet layer
- child layer
- child layer
- child layer (move this layer always  visible on top, only in layer planet)

Comment: @WestLangley thank you for assistance, I assume i cant solve it by easy way, i create another scene and another camera, it is complicated, but works like a charm.