# Collada building model whose interior objects disappear when viewed from certain angles

Tags: javascript, three.js, transparency, collada

so I'm working on a three.js project where I have the floor of a building saved as a collada file, there are additional collada objects saved into the scene in the form of some air zones (cuboids basically). You can move around the model using WASD and the mouse, however as the camera moves around the model, depending on the angle, some of the building floor or rooms will turn invisible allowing me to see the mesh plane at the lowest level of the model. I have been looking through SO for advice, and in general the COLLADA issues seems to be related to not having material double sided set properly, I have made the rooms and my floor double sided to test this, however this doesn't seem to have fixed the issue.

The prototype can be found at: http://danu2.it.nuigalway.ie/WebGLProject/

In the model I've temporarily raised the air zone cuboids while testing that the issue wasn't occurring due to mesh clashes. This doesn't seem to be the case.

Does anyone have any advice on what the likely culprit is, or a potential solution to the issue?

Comment: it is not clear if you want transparency or not because your entire model seems to be transparent.

Comment: Yes I want the air zones to be transparent (as they are), however the issue im raising is that when viewing the model from certain angles certain parts of the collada model go completely invisible, as can be seen when the grey floor disappears at certain sections when the camera is moved around (and thus the wiremesh floor appears underneath)

Comment: Perhaps "transparent" wasn't the best word to choose in my title in this case, all of the zones are transparent, but it can even be seen now that the zones are elevated that the sides of these cuboids seem to disappear when viewed at certain angles

Comment: this posting should help you understand transparency http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994944/transparent-objects-in-threejs

Comment: Thank you gaitat, I will follow up on where your link takes me, I still have more in depth reading to do, at first glance I'm still a bit confused as to its relevance as I would have thought that each of my objects was at a very distinct and separate distance from each other (particularly now that I have added extra spaces to the objects to test this) so I didn't expect any confusion from the rendering side of things.

Comment: As for the disappearing floor panels, this used not be a problem for me back when I originally worked on the project in r56, I feel like it only occurred since I updated all the way up to r71 and had to change some aspects of the code to get it working again.