# Make a tonnel in plane

Tags: javascript, three.js

[image]
[image]
[image]
Hello. I'm using THREE.js to visualise the room. How can I make a windows? Walls are planes. Window will be simple cube. How can I make a transparent toonel in plane?

Comment: Can't you add just a texture with window on the wall?

Comment: Similar topic:
[Transparent objects in Threejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994944/transparent-objects-in-threejs)