# Incorrect vision with using transparent objects

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using revision 71. 
How you can see on images, i can escape some objects in vision, when i am using transparent material. 
Sorry, i don't know how to explain my problem better.
`renderer.sortObjects = true`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: See if `renderOrder` helps you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994944/transparent-objects-in-threejs/15995475#15995475

Comment: thank you! I have used `transparenty = true` for all materials and if it was not transparent opacity was 1. Now I am using this, and it works: `opacity: (textures_library[colorSchemeID].opacity<1.0)?textures_library[colorSchemeID].opacity:undefined, transparent:(textures_library[colorSchemeID].opacity<1.0)?true:false`

Answer (score 0):

It's a common problem with no 'simple' solution. See here for details: [Transparency Sorting](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transparency_Sorting)

Comment: I think your answer is helpful, but I have found another solution