# Instancing - See Through 3D Objects

Tags: three.js, 3d, react-three-fiber

I have been trying to instance some tree meshes in react-three-fiber and threejs,
this is what i have got so far: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-sunset-74wmt?file=/src/App.js

The trees from one angle look see through, I am able to see the barks of ALL trees.
[image]

but the behavior is normal from the opposite angle.
[image]

To me it seems to be some issue with render order or meshes or the shader, not able to wrap my head around it.
I need the see-through thing to not happen and the set should look like how it looks like in the second picture from all angles

Comment: Alpha blending is _very_ sensitive to render order, and won't work well for the scene shown here – particularly with instancing, since three.js doesn't sort instanced objects on the fly. You should get much better results with alpha masking instead of alpha blending here though. If exporting from blender that's an "alpha clip" mode, or `material.alphaTest > 0` in three.js

Comment: Using Alpha clip on blender worked! thanks for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments by[Don McCurdy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1314762/don-mccurdy). I needed to use AlphaClip property on blender while exporting my mesh.

Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994944/transparent-objects-in-threejs) which was quite helpful in understanding the problems with threejs transparency at play

Updated with the solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-sunset-74wmt?file=/src/App.js