# three.js - How to use Object3d.renderOrder to control the z-index ?

Tags: three.js

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994944/transparent-objects-in-threejs), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514274/three-js-how-to-control-rendering-order) mentioned rederOrder, but it is undocumented. I set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4w56/y655cwqt/5/) and it does not work, what is wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/q4w56/y655cwqt/5/

```
// now mesh1 should be always on top of mesh2  
mesh1.renderOrder = 1 
mesh2.renderOrder = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `renderOrder` in three.js does not cause a renderable object to be "on top". It just controls the rendering order. It can be a useful tool if some objects are transparent. If all objects in the scene are opaque, changing the rendering order will (in typical use cases) have no effect on the rendered output.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666570/how-to-change-the-zorder-of-object-with-threejs/12666937#12666937) if you want some objects to render "on top".

three.js r.79

Comment: This is a rather late question, but does changing the renderOrder incur any cost? (internal reorganization of buffers and whatnot)

Comment: No, it does not.