# Render object through other objects

Tags: three.js

Inside my scene I have a THREE.Line with THREE.LineBasicMaterial next to many other objects. I want to render that line through every other object, like they are transparent for it.

I tried to use .renderDepth but it doesn't seem to do anything in that regard.

The approach I would use now is projecting the line onto a plane right infront of the camera. But that is rather complex and inefficient. Are there any simple solutions?

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666570/how-to-change-the-zorder-of-object-with-threejs/12666937#12666937

Comment: @WestLangley yes, that's what I was searching for. Except that I want the line to be like it is right in front of the camera, so it is unchanged by the zoom, but I guess that is easily done by creating another camera for the second scene and syncing it appropriately with the other camera. Thanks!