# threejs: rendering multiple scenes in a single webgl renderer

Tags: 3d, three.js, renderer, scene

I am trying to include multiple scene into a single webgl renderer as per code below:

renderer.render( scene1, camera );
renderer.render( scene2, camera );

I am facing issue where in the last scene object that is passed to the renderer is being painted and the previous one is not. I confirmed it by swapping the above two lines of code. I am newbie to threejs and would like to know if the above can be achieved? and also if you can guide me towards supporting examples (if any).

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666570/how-to-change-the-zorder-of-object-with-threejs/12666937#12666937

Comment: Thanks @WestLangley! the reference was helpful, finally got my example to work.

Comment: Arg, what was your solution!?

Answer (score 8):

The minimal solution you can find here: https://jsfiddle.net/mmalex/sqg0d8vx/

```
var animate = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    renderer.autoClear = true;

    //render scene1
    renderer.render(scene1, camera);

    //prevent canvas from being erased with next .render call
    renderer.autoClear = false;

    //just render scene2 on top of scene1
    renderer.render(scene2, camera);
};
```

Comment: The objects from both scenes still intersect. How do you make scene2 render on top of scene1 (so it is like two layers)?

Comment: insert "renderer.clearDepth();" right before you render the second scene
https://jsfiddle.net/7g3dkuwq/