# Make three js Scene Transparent

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, webgl, react-three-fiber

I have two scenes in my three js application. I need to set my one of the scene background to transparent. So that, the objects behind that scene will get displayed. How can I achieve this?

I have tried some options, like `renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);` and `const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });` in renderer. That's not working, It makes background to white, not transparent.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272190/threejs-rendering-multiple-scenes-in-a-single-webgl-renderer and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666570/how-to-change-the-zorder-of-object-with-threejs/12666937#12666937

Comment: Thanks for your reference. It worked. @vallentin