# using renderOrder in three.js

Tags: three.js, render, overlap, zbuffer

I want to have two overlapping objects in a scene but I want to define which object should be drawn first. I have a sample of the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/sg02e5sm/1/

I'm using `renderOrder = 1` for the second object to make it appear always on top of the first object (as long as they have the same Z value), but it's not working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`renderOrder` does not make something appear "on top". It controls the order in which objects are rendered.

If you want your 2nd plane to be "on top", you can add

```
mesh.material.depthTest = false;
```

for the 2nd plane.

Alternatively, you can implement two render passes, as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666570/how-to-change-the-zorder-of-object-with-threejs/12666937#12666937).

three.js r.142