# Custom distance of view for one sky plane

Tags: three.js

Is it possible to set a specific distance of view for one plane in scene? Like different camera.far for just one object. I need sky plane to be entirely visible, not like other objects.

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stAKG.jpg)

Comment: do you mean skybox ..?? what is your question

Comment: I use a plane instead of box. The question is how to make the whole plane visible while visibility of other objects are reduced by camera.far parameter.

Comment: @Kempston Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666570/how-to-change-the-zorder-of-object-with-threejs/12666937#12666937) work for your purposes? You would use two cameras, each with different `far` settings.

Comment: Yes, it works. I've already seen that. Thanks. But in that case there is another problem. I need shadows from the clouds on the ground and on all the objects of my scene. With different scenes and cameras it seems to be impossible.