# renderOrder doesn't work when the scene has transparent objects

Tags: three.js

I want to render a opaque object behind all my transparent objects by setting `mesh.renderOrder = 9999` as well as `material.depthTest = false` for all my opaque objects. But the render order seems doesn't work when my scene has transparent objects. My opaque objects get blended with the transparent objects.

It works well when all the objects are opaque. But when I set the material of some of the objects to `transparent = true`, the render order seems doesn't work.

I've already set `renderer.sortObject = true`. I don't want to set it to `false` because I can't control the order of loading my objects.

Is there any way to render opaque objects after transparent objects?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666570/how-to-change-the-zorder-of-object-with-threejs/12666937#12666937. `renderOrder` does not control what is "in front" or "on top" -- it controls the render order only.

Comment: @WestLangley I know. So I disable `depthTest` and make it render at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three renders opaque objects first, then transparent objects, and then possibly sprites. `renderOrder` does not affect this, it only affects nodes **within** the group (sorting of opaque, and then sorting of transparent). You can try to render multiple scenes, and shift things around.

Comment: Makes the behavior make sense