# Three Js get all elements from multiple scene

Tags: three.js

I have multiple scene like => [How to change the zOrder of object with Threejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666570/how-to-change-the-zorder-of-object-with-threejs).

I want to select now an element with a Raycast, but I get one raycast for each scene, how can I handle all taken elements from all scenes at ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to add all objects of both scenes into a separate array. In the next step, you use this array in order to call `Raycaster.intersectObjects()` like this:

```
raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );
```